# Duplicate Rule Details - How to get in Apex exception

Tags: apex, exception, duplicate-management, duplicate-value

I am getting a duplicate rule issue with apex

> first error: DUPLICATES_DETECTED, Use one of these records?: []

Now I want this rule to run, however, I need to get the details of the record that is being suggested by Salesforce duplicate management. How can I get the record details that is being suggested in Apex and show it as part of error message?

Let me know for any further details.!!

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [DuplicateResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm) class to get duplicate records detected by duplicate rule.

Using `Database.SaveResult saveResult = Database.insert(contact, false);` get errors and successes. You may need to do few tweaks in code to get duplicate records.

```
for (Database.Error error : saveResult.getErrors()) {
     if (error instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {
         Database.DuplicateError duplicateError = (Database.DuplicateError)error;
         Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = duplicateError.getDuplicateResult();

         ApexPages.Message errorMessage = new ApexPages.Message(
                            ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Duplicate Error: ' + 
                            duplicateResult.getErrorMessage());
         ApexPages.addMessage(errorMessage);

         this.duplicateRecords = new List<sObject>();

         Datacloud.MatchResult[] matchResults = duplicateResult.getMatchResults();

         Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult = matchResults[0];
         Datacloud.MatchRecord[] matchRecords = matchResult.getMatchRecords();
     }
}
```

You can use `Datacloud.MatchResult` to get duplicate records. Please find the [sample code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm#apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult).